How to determine pingInterval time in websocket?
I'm working with websocket.
When network connection is blocked, we have to detect it quickly.
So I'd like to set pingInterval time as small.
But current user number isn't small. So when user number increase, server load will increase.
So I'd like to know how to determine proper pingInterval time.
I know how to set pingInterval time, but don't know to determine.
we used default pingInterval, but it's too lazy.
